# Extracting information from a file variable in d3 pick basic

Tags: pick

I have a file variable in d3 pick basic and I am trying to figure out what file it corresponds to.

I tried the obvious thing which was to say:

```
print f *suppose the file variable's name is f in this case
```

but that didn't work, because:

```
SELECTION: 58[B34] in program "FILEPRINTER", Line 7:  File variable used 
where string expression expected.
```

I also tried things like:

```
list f *didn't compile
execute list dict f *same error
execute list f *same error
```

but those also did not work.

In case any one is wondering, the reason I am trying to do this in the first place is that there is a global variable that is passed up and down in the code base I am working with, but I can't find where the global variable gets its value from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That file pointer variable is called a "file descriptor". You can't get any information from it.

You can use the file-of-files to log Write events, and after a Write is performed by the code, check to see what file was updated. The details for doing this would be a bit cumbersome. You really should rely on the Value-Add Reseller or contract with competent assistance for this.

If this is not a live end-user system, you can also modify an item getting written with some very unique text like "WHAT!FILE!IS!THIS?". Then you can do a Search-System command to search the entire account (or system) to find that text. See docs for proper use of that command.

This is probably the best option... Inject the following:

```
IF @USER = "CRISZ" THEN ; * substitute your user ID
  READU FOO FROM F,"BLAH" ELSE
    DEBUG
    RELEASE F,"BLAH"
  END
END
```

That code will stop only for one person - for everyone else it will flow as normal. When it does stop, use the LIST-LOCKS command to see which file has a read lock for item "BLAH". That's your file! Don't forget to remove and recompile the code. Note that recompiling code while users are actively using it results in aborts. It's best to do this kind of thing after hours or on a test system.

If you can't modify the code like that, diagnostics like this can be difficult. If the above suggestions don't help, I think this challenge might be beyond your personal level of experience yet and recommend you get some help.

If suggestion here Does help, please flag this as the answer. :)

Comment: Unfortunately the only completely functional version of the program we have is in a production environment, so locking the table won't work.

Comment: That doesn't lock an entire table. It just locks the single record (which doesn't exist) for that file. No one is affected (as if I'd suggest you lock up all of your users. :) ). Just list-locks, see the file name, then hit G to Go from the Debug line. It will continue and end. Then you have the file name and you can remove the test code.

Comment: If your question is answered, please flag this response. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if this would actually work because I didn't end up trying it; I figured out where the variables get set obviating the need to do this, but it certainly seems reasonable.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for flagging this as the answer. I can guarantee it will work as this is a common technique for finding issues, so if you need to do some debugging on a live system, or if you need to check the lock table, check back here. Looking forward to more questions.